# peer dependencies issue and token issue when installing semantic-release/gitlab

Tags: gitlab, npm-install, access-token, semantic-versioning, semantic-release

I'm currently learning how to use semantic-release/gitlab to get automate versioning after pushing to my branch, but when I tried the command below in bash:(directory is in my project folder)

```
npm install -g semantic-release/gitlab
```

I got warning

```
npm WARN @semantic-release/gitlab@0.0.0-development requires a peer of semantic-release@>=15.8.0 <16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+@semantic-release/gitlab@0.0.0-development
added 85 packages from 101 contributors in 89.758s
```

I also tried

```
npm install --save-dev semantic-release/gitlab
```

This gave me similar warning as above.

Then I followed a tutorial, trying to get npm token & Gitlab private token,
when I try:

```
$ ./.npmrc
```

it gave me this:

```
 line 1: //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=: No such file or directory
```

How can I get a npm token?

I'm not sure what to do now and what's the next step, can someone help me, and it would be great if someone can send a instruction that I can follow. I've been stuck for a whole day now, please help!!!!Many thanks.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/tree/master/docs/usage#usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning tells you what to do, you have to install semantic-release as it's a peer dependency. You can install just like you installed `semantic-release/gitlab`: `npm install semantic-release --save-dev`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I did some research and found out there're two different plugins 'semantic-release/gitlab' & 'semantic-release-gitlab', what's the difference? I updated something in my question, I also have issues when getting the npm tokens, would be great if you can help me. Many thanks.